# Calls to non static member functions have a hidden parameter that is accessible in the definition of the member function as *this

Tags: c++

Can somebody explain this:

> Calls to non static member functions have a hidden parameter that is accessible in the definition of the member function as `*this`. For a member function of `myClass`, the hidden parameter is usually of type `MyClass&` (for non const member). This is somewhat surprising given that this has a pointer type. It would have been nicer to make this equivalent to what is now `*this`. However, this was part of an early version of C++ before reference types were part of the language, and by the time reference types were added, too much code already depended on this being a pointer

Thank you!

Comment: Which part of it are you having trouble with?

Comment: 1) "hidden parameters" what is it?? 2) The part following: "this is somewhat surprising..."

Comment: `*this` is what `self` is in a couple of languages. are you familiar with ruby or python?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ruby nor python

Comment: The explanation is poorly worded. The type of `this` is `MyClass*`, but yes, a reference would have been better.

Comment: That's a pretty bad explanation, although the wording in the standard isn't any clearer: "the expression `this` is a prvalue of type 'pointer to cv-qualifier-seq X'".

Comment: Thanks, this comment is actually useful.

Answer (score 1):

This example:

```
class C
{
 public:
   int i;
   void f(int j) { i = j; }
};
...
C c;
c.f(1);
```

Is interpreted somewhat (not exactly) like this by the compiler:

```
class C
{
 public:
   int i;
};
void C_f(C *this, int j) { this->i = j; }
...
C c;
C_f(&c, 1);
```

That's all. The methods are separated from the variable data in the object.

The rest of the text just says why a pointer is used, instead of a reference `C &p`.

Something like this would be possible too:

```
class C
{
 public:
   int i;
};
void C_f(C &this, int j) { this.i = j; }
...
C c;
C_f(c, 1);
```

IOW using a reference instead of a pointer => no manual work with addresses etc.
But as it is, `this` is only the address/pointer of the object. Because of historical reasons.

Comment: And of course, it gets massively more complicated if you have virtual functions and you call through a derived class instance.